# How can I combine two docker images into one?

Tags: docker

The title may be a bit weird and misleading, basically what I want to do is:

I need a node.js server that runs the following script from the dockerfile below. I don't want to run docker inside docker, so I need to combine the script and nodejs server, but don't know how, since I'm quite new to docker.

Should I add a configuration for the node js environment in the dockerfile below, or create a new dockerfile that depends on this one? And what should I do? Nevertheless, how do I do it?

```
FROM leon/usd:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/ufg

# Configuration
ARG UFG_RELEASE="3bf441e0eb5b6cfbe487bbf1e2b42b7447c43d02"
ARG UFG_SRC="/usr/src/ufg"
ARG UFG_INSTALL="/usr/local/ufg"
ENV USD_DIR="/usr/local/usd"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${USD_DIR}/lib:${UFG_SRC}/lib"
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${UFG_INSTALL}/bin"
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${UFG_INSTALL}/python"

# Build + install usd_from_gltf
RUN git init && \
    git remote add origin https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf.git && \
    git fetch --depth 1 origin "${UFG_RELEASE}" && \
    git checkout FETCH_HEAD && \
    python "${UFG_SRC}/tools/ufginstall/ufginstall.py" -v "${UFG_INSTALL}" "${USD_DIR}" && \
    cp -r "${UFG_SRC}/tools/ufgbatch" "${UFG_INSTALL}/python" && \
    rm -rf "${UFG_SRC}" "${UFG_INSTALL}/build" "${UFG_INSTALL}/src"

RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
# Start the service

ENTRYPOINT ["usd_from_gltf"]
CMD ["usd_from_gltf"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use own docker-entrypoint where you can combine what you want. For example bash script in docker-entrypoint.sh
Now you have to use "COPY" in Dockerfile and change your ENTRYPOINT to new one like this :

```
FROM leon/usd:latest
WORKDIR /
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .
WORKDIR /usr/src/ufg

# Configuration
...
...
#Last Line
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```